# Base Internationalization doesn't work in custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I create a subclass of `UILabel`, in which I set font for its text(and this is the only thing I do in this subclass):

```
 [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"mplus-1c-regular" size:14.0]];
```

I use Base Internationalization to do i18n for my project, this is the related translation in my `storybaord.strings`:

```
"kjN-FS-SlD.text" = "進步來自精準分析。";
```

If I set this subclass as the custom class of this label in interface builder, this translation doesn't work. It shows English text, which is my default language of base internationalization, just like my system language is English. However, if I don't set the custom class(leave it blank), it works as normal.

How can I make it work for my custom class?

Comment: What do you mean by "translation doesn't work"? What do you see?

Comment: it shows english text, which is the default of my Base Internationalization, just like I set my default system language as english.